# should I dump all the variables inside data property in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

1st approach

```
<script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return {
        data1: "some data",
        data2: "some more data"
      }
    },
    methods: {
      dataActions(){
        this.data1 = "new data";
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

2nd approach

```
<script>
  let data1 = "some data";
  let data2 = "some more data";

  export default {
    methods: {
      dataActions(){
        data1 = "new data";
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

which one should I prefer assuming that data is not used in `<template>`.

does it affect my code?

I know that the data in the data property is mutating values. But should I use the 2nd approach if I don't want mutating values?

and can I pass the data1 in the 2nd approach as props to components?

Answer (score 2):

`data` is not for mutating values - it is for reactive values.

If you want your page re-rendered when a variable changes, then put it in `data`

Otherwise keep it outside - mutable or otherwise.

For eg., if your template uses any of these variables, then `data` is the right place for them.

`props` is good to pass data into the component. But if page gets re-rendered the component will get reinitialized.

Comment: yes that's what i thought......if I don't use the variables on the page i could put them outside the data....cuz `data` turns it into a proxy which take unnecessary space I think. And mutating i meant reactive, sry my bad.